# Ruby handle up arrow for shell style interface

Tags: ruby, shell

I am implementing a simple shell style interface in ruby as follows:

```
exit = false
while(not exit)
        print '?> '
        case gets("\n").strip
        when "quit"
                exit = true
        when "xxx"
            #handle xxx command 
        end
end
```

If I press the up arrow, I get ^[[A. 
Is there anyway to implement this as would be done in a shell where it fills in the previous command?

Comment: 1) don't shadow methods (`Kernel#exit`) with variables of the same name. 2) Use `until`, not `while not`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use readline for this.  Ruby has an implementation: http://bogojoker.com/readline/

Here is the ruby api for it http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/readline/rdoc/index.html